# Pre-compiled header is not used when including standard library

Tags: c++, g++, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to create a pre-compiled header and use it when compiling a cpp file. I have the 2 following files:
main.cpp:

```
#include "foo.hpp"

int main()
{
    myTemplate<int> obj;

    return 0;
}
```

and foo.hpp:

```
#ifndef FOO_HPP
#define FOO_HPP

template<class T>
class myTemplate
{
};

#endif
```

I'm running this command to create a gch file

```
g++ -std=c++11 foo.hpp
```

Then I'm making the object file, using the -H flag to see what files are being used

```
g++ -std=c++11 -H -c main.cpp
```

and the output is

```
! foo.hpp.gch
 main.cpp
```

Good. The gch file is being used.

Now I insert this line at the beginning of main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
```

Now when I'm trying to create the object file, with the same command as before, I get a long list of files (most of them are from the standard library of course) but none of them is foo.hpp.gch. I do see foo.hpp in the list.
Why does it make a difference?
How can I use a pre-compiled header when making an object file, when the header includes the standard library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here my comment as an answer:

Include the precompiled header first and then the standard library.

This behaviour is probably, because the compiler can not know if the not-precompiled header (here the standard library) changes e.g. some macro definitions that influence the precompiled header and make it invalid.
(Maybe someone could verify this, since it's only a guess)